# php mysql If I do not have the same data between two tables, can I print the other table data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

php mysql If the value in the 'x' table is not in the 'y' table, print the data in the 'x' table?

Mysql Query:

```
SELECT * FROM andesite_advertisement INNER JOIN andesite_adsrice ON (andesite_adsrice.adsrice_adsase = andesite_advertisement.advertisement_base)
```

[image]

Comment: you might want to describe your problem a bit better, including what you have tried so far to achieve what you want. This way you won't get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) or [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) syntax:

```
SELECT IF(table1.age > 18, table1.user, table2.user)
FROM ...
```

It works like so (From the documentation):

> If the first argument is TRUE, `IF()` returns the second argument. Otherwise, it returns the third argument.
>
> ```
> mysql> SELECT IF(1>2,2,3);
>     -> 3
> mysql> SELECT IF(1<2,'yes','no');
>     -> 'yes'
> mysql> SELECT IF(STRCMP('test','test1'),'no','yes');
>     -> 'no'
> ```

Further EDIT (In regards to your updated question). I believe what you're looking for is a `LEFT JOIN`. If the data doesn't exist in the alternate table, you will still return a row in the database (But any columns in the associated table will return null). Then you can either get the data programattically in PHP, or using something like `IF(andesite_adsrice.adsrice_adsase IS NULL, andesite_advertisement.column1, andesite_adsrice.column1)`.

Comment: Understand :/

`SELECT * FROM andesite_advertisement INNER JOIN andesite_adsrice ON (andesite_adsrice.adsrice_adsase = andesite_advertisement.advertisement_base)`

Comment: That doesn't really help. You should read, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated the query.

Comment: @OsmanCakmak You're doing a join on that column: `andesite_adsrice.adsrice_adsase = andesite_advertisement.advertisement_base` so isn't the data always going to be the same?

Comment: If I had already asked 6 hours later, print it out and the sql command was wrong. I fixed it. The problem is that the user has registered and the printout in the table of ads is not in the table of received ads.